# Game Maker Studio writing in exactly in the middle of a GUI

Tags: game-maker

I'd like to make a pause screen.

In the game the view follows the character and when paused I want the text to be exactly in the middle of the screen.  I am using a draw GUI event to display text where the user can see it.

I was thinking of halving the length and width of the port but could not find a function which gave those numbers.

If there is one, what it is, and if not how can I achieve this?

Comment: Might be better suited to http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ - although if you're doing it using their scripting language (rather than the GUI editor) it should be on topic here too.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved this.

In the GUI event, I use `view_hport[0]` and `view_wport[0]` in order to obtain the total length of the port then halve this number.

Comment: It's a wrong way. You should use `display_get_gui_width()` and `display_get_gui_height()` functions. Because GUI size may differ with port size.